# Deleting 15000 Empty rows from data but code is extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba

Developed below code to delete the number of rows if it is empty code works fine but it takes a lot of time for processing.

It should be faster. I hope to get some help. Thanks

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    lastRow = ws.Range("Y" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("Y2:Y" & lastRow)

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `ClearContents` before doing the delete. It may not help much, but it will speed it up.

Comment: Tried to clear the contents but it takes same time to delete the rows

Comment: Strat from the last row and work up - otherwise excel has to move all the other rows up each time it deletes one.

Comment: Are there any formulas, formats, conditional formatting which will be affected by deletion of the rows?

Comment: There is nothing that can be affected @Naresh

Comment: Then, instead of deleting the rows, can you copy and paste the filtered data on other sheet and rename that sheet as original name after deleting the original?

Comment: I gave you a suggestion for you to apply - check on here, it has been done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Non-Matching Rows

- This will not delete any rows but will only overwrite. It will only work if your data are values because any formulas would be overwritten with values.
- For simplicity's sake, the data must be contiguous and has to start in cell `A1` (`CurrentRegion`).
- Both solutions do the same. In a sample of 100k rows with 33k matches, the first took 3 seconds, while the second took 5 seconds (`Application.Match` is kind of slow applied to an array).
- You have severely modified your question. To make the second solution work for the current question (*delete empty rows*), you could get rid of the 3 lines containing `Criteria` and use:

  ```
  If Len(CStr(Data(r, Col))) > 0 Then
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Long = 25
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Trans,Hub" ' *** If you add here...
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Data Range ('srg') (no headers).
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    If rCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data rows
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = rCount - 1
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = rg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    Debug.Print srg.Address
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the 'matching' values to the top of the array.
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    ' *** ... you also have to add here...
    Dim Crit1 As String: Crit1 = UCase(Criteria(0))
    Dim Crit2 As String: Crit2 = UCase(Criteria(1))
    ' *** ... meaning here...
    
    Dim r As Long ' Rows Counter
    Dim c As Long ' Columns Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Matching Rows Counter
    For r = 1 To srCount
        Select Case UCase(CStr(Data(r, Col)))
        Case Crit1, Crit2 ' *** ... and here.
            n = n + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(n, c) = Data(r, c)
            Next c
        End Select
    Next r
    If n = srCount Then Exit Sub ' all matches
    
    ' Write the matching values ('n') from the array to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.Resize(n, cCount)
    Debug.Print drg.Address
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Clear contents of the Clear Range,
    ' i.e. the range below the Destination Range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = srg.Resize(srCount - n).Offset(n)
    Debug.Print crg.Address
    crg.ClearContents

End Sub

Sub DeleteRowsApplicationMatch()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Long = 25
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Trans,Hub"
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Data Range ('srg') (no headers).
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    If rCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data rows
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = rCount - 1
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = rg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    Debug.Print srg.Address
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the 'matching' values to the top of the array.
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    Dim r As Long ' Rows Counter
    Dim c As Long ' Columns Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Matching Rows Counter
    For r = 1 To srCount
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CStr(Data(r, Col)), Criteria, 0)) Then
            n = n + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(n, c) = Data(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    If n = srCount Then Exit Sub ' all matches
    
    ' Write the matching values ('n') from the array to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.Resize(n, cCount)
    Debug.Print drg.Address
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Clear contents of the Clear Range,
    ' i.e. the range below the Destination Range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = srg.Resize(srCount - n).Offset(n)
    Debug.Print crg.Address
    crg.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working beyond the expectation thank you very much @VBasic2008 but it works for first criteria that is `Trans` it works for first value before `,` if its `Trans` or `Hub` do not work for the value after `,`

Comment: Make sure that `CriteriaList` has no spaces: `"Trans,Hub"` not `"Trans, Hub"`. The code is written for whole words in cells. If `Trans` or `Hub` are only parts of the contents of the matching cells, it has to the modified.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting 15000 rows in Excel/VBA is very slow.

Instead of accessing every single row *individually*, try creating an **empty array** to delete all data.

```
Dim yourArray As Variant
ReDim yourArray(1 To 15000, 1 To 2)

For k = 0 To 15000
    yourArray(1 + k, 1) = ""
    yourArray(1 + k, 2) = ""
    ' array(row, column)
Next k

' ...

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(15000, 2)) = yourArray
```

Keep in mind that it will still take a few seconds and not be done in an instant as you might hope it would. Excel and VBA just isn't that fast.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but i am unable to modify it @Lynx

Comment: This would delete (clear) all data, but OP want just to delete the filtered rows

Comment: Oh right, I see my mistake. With my solution, the rows would be emptied but still existing as empty entries. In that case, I have to admit I know of no faster VBA-way than the regular ".Delete", which admittedly takes ""some"" time. Maybe it's faster to clear them before deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting first then do the delete on the selection:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    lastRow = ws.Range("Y" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("Y2:Y" & lastRow)

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but its still slow.